# Javascript function to validate password strength (with special characters)

Tags: javascript, html, passwords

I am trying to create a function to validate password strength which includes verification for at least 1 special character. The code below validates everything except for special character and password min length. Would anyone be so kind to help me spot what I did wrong?

**Password field:**

```
    <input type="password" id="password_1" name="password_1" pattern="^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^*-&]).{8,}$" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, at least one special character, and its length should be at least 8 characters" required>
```

**Message display:**

```
<div id="message">
  <h3>Password must contain the following:</h3>
  <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
  <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
  <p id="number" class="invalid">A <b>number</b></p>
  <p id="special" class="invalid">A <b>special</b> character</p>
  <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 characters</b></p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript function:**

```js
  var myInput = document.getElementById("password_1");
  var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
  var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
  var number = document.getElementById("number");
  var special = document.getElementById("special");
  var length = document.getElementById("length");


  myInput.onfocus = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
  }


  myInput.onblur = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
  }


  myInput.onkeyup = function() {
    var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {
      letter.classList.remove("invalid");
      letter.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      letter.classList.remove("valid");
      letter.classList.add("invalid");
    }

    var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {
      capital.classList.remove("invalid");
      capital.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      capital.classList.remove("valid");
      capital.classList.add("invalid");
    }

    var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {
      number.classList.remove("invalid");
      number.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      number.classList.remove("valid");
      number.classList.add("invalid");
    }


    var special = /[@$!%*?&]/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(special)) {
      special.classList.remove("invalid");
      special.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      special.classList.remove("valid");
      special.classList.add("invalid");
    }

    if(myInput.value.length >= 8) {
      length.classList.remove("invalid");
      length.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      length.classList.remove("valid");
      length.classList.add("invalid");
    }
  }
```

Comment: There's a lot of work done here. It's [much easier](https://jsfiddle.net/632aqskf/1/) ... Let the machine do the work for you, you don't have to concern about every element separately.

Comment: Hello @Teemu. Your solution is very neat. Thank you very much!